# Создание Json объекта в Kotlin

Tags: json, kotlin

Столкнулся с проблемой создания Json. У меня есть три поля в моём классе:

```
    class AdvancedSearchSnippetRequests(
    val Documents: ArrayList<SearchSnippetRequestsFields> = arrayListOf()
) {
    class SearchSnippetRequestsFields(
        val Sort: Int,
        val ModuleID: Int? = 98,
        val Id: Int
    )
}
```

мне нужно сделать функцию, которая должна принимать список Id и сделать в конечном этого JSON следующего вида для отправки к сервису:

```
"Documents": [
    {
        "Sort": 1,
        "ModuleID": 98,
        "Id": 111111
    },        
    {
        "Sort": 2,
        "ModuleID": 98,
        "Id": 222222
    }
    ,        
    {
        "Sort": 3,
        "ModuleID": 98,
        "Id": 333333
    }
    ...
```

Список Id наполнен тестовыми значениями [111111,222222,333333], может включать в себя разное количество Id, от этого и должно варьироваться кол-во объектов в JSON. В данный момент у меня работает если в функцию подставляю через object.Mapper значение Id, но только на один запрос один объект, а нужно разом добавить к примеру 10 id, получить один большой JSON в 10 объектов и отправить разом в сервис, что бы не  отправлять по одному каждый раз.

```
    @ValueSource(
        strings = ["14391033", "14391528"]
    )
    @Test
    fun testC4556800_AdvancedSearchSnippets(Id: Int) {
        val requestJson = ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(
   AdvancedSearchSnippetRequests(
        Documents = arrayListOf(
            SearchSnippetRequestsFields(
                Id = Id
            )
        )
    )
)
}
```

Нужно избавиться от @ValueSource сделать обычный список и подавать его на вход функции которая сделает JSON с несколькими объектами на основе id которые ей поступили, сколько Id поступило, столько и объектов внутри.

Answer (score 0):

```
val listDocId = arrayListOf<Int>(
            14391033,
            14391528,
            56890077,
            56907014,
            56907971,
            56893082,
            56886341,
            56889852,
            56876771,
            56889980
        )

        val requestJson = ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(AdvancedSearchSnippetRequests(listDocId))
```

Создал список со значениями и отправил его в класс где сделал реализацию.

```
    class AdvancedSearchSnippetRequests(list: List<Int>) {
    val Documents: ArrayList<SearchSnippetRequestsFields> = arrayListOf()

    init {
        list.map {
            this.Documents.add(SearchSnippetRequestsFields(Documents.size + 1, it))
        }
    }
}

class SearchSnippetRequestsFields(Sort: Int, Id: Int) {
    val Sort: Int? = Sort
    val ModuleID: Int? = 98
    val Id: Int? = Id

}
```